# Overwriting one data with another data in pandas(dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, timer

Periodically (every 120 seconds) get data but recent data overwrites previous data in SQL DB. I want all data to be saved.In addition, is the timer correct?

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import psycopg2
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd
import json
import time

start_time = time.time()
while True:
    temp = pd.DataFrame()
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    vehicleList = {"SN63NBK", "YY67UTP"}
    for ids in vehicleList:
        r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Vehicle/' + ids + '/Arrivals')

        r = r.text
        temp = pd.read_json(r)
        temp['Type'] = 'ids'
        df = pd.concat([df, temp], sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:3434@127.0.0.1/postgres')
    df['timing'] = list(map(lambda x: json.dumps(x), df['timing']))
    df.to_sql('tfl_bus_pg6', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
time.sleep(120.0 - ((time.time() - start_time) % 120.0))
```

Comment: Is the data being overwritten in the SQL database? If so, you could try ```if_exists='append'```

Comment: the [link](https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Vehicle/YY67UTP/Arrivals) you're trying to access with `YY67UTP` id doesn't contain any info

Comment: @K753 if_exists='append' done!. thx.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code slightly, but I think the main problem is in `if_exists` parameter which you should set to `append`, as @K753 have mentioned in the comments.

Also, `YY67UTP` id returns nothing, so I replaced it with another random id from the site to illustrate how code works.

```py
def _data_gen(vehicles):
    """ Yields a dataframe for each request """
    for ids in vehicles:
        time.sleep(1)
        r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Vehicle/' + ids + '/Arrivals')
        temp = pd.read_json(r.text)
        temp['Type'] = ids
        yield temp

while True:
    # how do you break from while loop if you need to?
    vehicleList = {"SN63NBK", "YY67UTP"}
    df = pd.concat(_data_gen(vehicleList), sort=False, ignore_index=True)

    engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:3434@127.0.0.1/postgres')
    df['timing'] = list(map(lambda x: json.dumps(x), df['timing']))
    df.to_sql('tfl_bus_pg6', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: this is happened (if_exists='append'). Thank you. I've tried your code but this was error : sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)

Comment: @istanbul34 that's strange because I kept your code regarding `engine` and `.to_sql` unchanged. Great that it works with `append` nevertheless